# Using variables in search and replace in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have some XML files in a directory and I am trying to replace the text `<value>hello</hello>` with text `<value>helloWorld</value>` using below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=hello
VAR2=helloWorld

find ./myFolder/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/<value>$VAR1<\/value>/<value>$VAR2<\/value>/g' '{}' \;
```

If I directly place the values instead of using variables VAR1 and VAR2 then the command is working fine and replacing the text properly.

But when I am using the variables as shown in above script then the replace is not happening. Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: This is a __FAQ__: Use __double quotes__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use double quotes if you want to include shell variables in strings, like this:

```
find ./myFolder/ -type f -exec sed -i "s?<value>$VAR1</value>?<value>$VAR2</value>?g" '{}' \;
```

Otherwise `$VAR1` will be taken literally as "$VAR1" instead of "hello", and the same goes for `$VAR2` as well.

I also changed the separator in the `sed` command from `s///` to `s???` to make it more readable when working with html tags.

Answer (score 2):

You should use double quotes around your sed replace string.

Also, `VAR2` doesn't have a `$` in front.

```
find ./myFolder/ -type f -exec sed -i "s/<value>$VAR1<\/value>/<value>VAR2<\/value>/g" '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks elimirks, I updated my query to include the missing $

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use double quotes around `sed command` to allow shell to expand variables:

```
find ./myFolder/ -type f -exec sed -i "s/<value>$VAR1<\/value>/<value>$VAR2<\/value>/g" '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, so is it mandatory to use double quotes whenever we use variables like this in UNIX? or this is applicable only with `sed` command?

Comment: Whenever using variables in shell you have to use double quotes otherwise shell won't expand variables.

Comment: Use double quotes by default in shell. There are cases where you must not use quotes at all but those are unusual and you must know exactly what you're trying to achieve when you do that.